# Add a page break in html for PDFKit in Swift

Tags: html, swift, pdfkit

I'm creating a PDF with HTML and PDFKit as follows:

```swift
let contextString = "<p style=\"page-break-after: always;\">hello</p><p>This is a test</p>"

let print = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: contextString)

let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
render.addPrintFormatter(print, startingAtPageAt: 0)

let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
render.setValue(page, forKey: "paperRect")
render.setValue(page, forKey: "printableRect")

let pdfData = NSMutableData()
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)

for i in 0..<render.numberOfPages {
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
}
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)

UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I added a page break after the first `<p>`. This works a bit to well. It makes two page breaks and the 2nd `<p>` doesn't show at all.

Does anyone have experience with that?
How can I add a page break in the PDF?

Comment: Looks like you spelt `style` wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get your code working with a single change to your contextString.

By changing it to `page-break-before` instead of `page-break-after` it seems to work. This is what I changed your contextString to, I used a multiline string as it is easier to read and gave it some clearer content.

```
let contextString = """
<p>Content in page 1</p>
<p style=\"page-break-before: always;\"></p>
<p>Content in page 2</p>
"""
```

Here is a very simple example that you could drop into Xcode.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.setTitle("Print", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        ])
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }

    @objc func tapped() {

        let contextString = """
        <p>Content in page 1</p>
        <p style=\"page-break-before: always;\"></p>
        <p>Content in page 2</p>
        """

        let print = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: contextString)


        let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
        render.addPrintFormatter(print, startingAtPageAt: 0)

        let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
        render.setValue(page, forKey: "paperRect")
        render.setValue(page, forKey: "printableRect")

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)

        for i in 0..<render.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
            render.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
        }
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

        let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)

        self.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here is a gif of it showing the two pages with the text:

[image: gif showing text added to both pages]

Comment: Works like a charm. Weird that page-break-after doesn't work. Still thank you!