# Working with PDFKit: How to make page breaks?

Tags: swift, pdfkit

Looking for some direction

I'm working with PDFKit. Everything is going fine but having trouble finding the methods (documentation / WWDC / elsewhere ) on how to stop text from drawing at a certain y position and start the next page. Any saved references or a snippet of code would be a great help.

Comment: Did you check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222073/add-a-page-break-in-html-for-pdfkit-in-swift

Comment: That does work but I don’t think it’s dynamic. I only want to do a page break if I get past a certain page height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know, wether this is the best way to implement your use case, but it worked for me.
When adding a new line into the PDF_Context, I recalculate a variable the keeps tracking of the current content height of my PDF_Page. When it exceeds a certain value, I create a NEW page, set the content height to zero and go on filling, ...

And you might wanna find some good answers, practices HERE -> [RayWenderlich.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit)

```
// my initial value
private var myCurrentPageContentHeight: CGFloat = 20
        
// in your PDF fill procedures add something like
myCurrentPageContentHeight += 40
            
// I also have a struct the encapsulates 
// PageSize with padding, ...
            
enum PDF_PageSize {
     case din_A4_Portrait
     case din_A4_Landscape
                
      // -------------------------------
      // getPDF_TotalRect
      // -------------------------------
      func getPDF_TotalRect() -> CGRect {
           switch self {
           case .din_A4_Portrait : return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595, height: 842)
           case .din_A4_Landscape : return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 842, height: 595)
           }
 }
 // ....
 }
```

Comment: I won’t be able to try your answer on my code for a bit but will update if it works.

Comment: It does look like what I’ve been looking for though

Comment: I added a link to a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich from 2019